# Redirecting users to a 404 page by using pretty urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, methods, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a mvc project just for fun.
Pretty urls already work, but i can't find a good way with my code to send visitors to a 404 page, in case the page doesn't exist which people are looking for.

```
class Route
{
       private $_uri = array();
       private $_method = array();

    /*
     * Builds a collection of internal URL's to look for
     * @param type $uri
     */
    public function add($uri, $method = null)
    {
        $this->_uri[] = '/' . trim($uri, '/');

        if($method != null){
            $this->_method[] = $method;
        }
    }

    public function submit()
    {

        $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri']) ? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';

        foreach($this->_uri as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match("#^$value$#",$uriGetParam)){
                if(is_string($this->_method[$key])){
                    $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                    new $useMethod();
                }
                else{
                    call_user_func($this->_method[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't analyze your code thoroughly (I couldn't, not sure what is the example route / method you're adding with ->add), but the solution seems simple to me:

```
public function submit()
{

    $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri']) ? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';
    $routeFound = false;
    foreach($this->_uri as $key => $value){
        if(preg_match("#^$value$#",$uriGetParam)){
            if(is_string($this->_method[$key])){
                $routeFound = true; 
                $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                new $useMethod();
            }
            else{
                $routeFound = true; 
                call_user_func($this->_method[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$routeFound){ 
        http_response_code(404);
        echo 'ooooh, not found'; 
        //or:
        include('404.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

p.s. http_response_code is a built-in function:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

edit: you could put the code starting with 'http_response_code(404);' to a separate function and just call it.

Comment: The method is basically the name of a controller, new $useMethod, calls a specific controller that renders a page. Is it required to use that built in php function for the 404 page, or can i do it without the function?

Comment: @JornReed oh, sorry for the delay. No, you don't need that function, you can simply use the header function, see the first comment in manual though: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#92305

Comment: Thanks! am i able to get your skype (in case you have it), to ask some more questions, about this project of mine?

Comment: @JornReed - hmm, no, I use skype/other chats only very occasionally, ask your questions here, on SO (StackOverflow). There is also a chat on SO, although I'm not active there, I've heard you can find helpful ppl: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php